# switch theme on fly

Tags: customization, themes

I have two themes: "Default" and "Alternate".

I'd like to place a link on my site that says "Switch to Alternate Theme", which will change the default theme to the alternate and vice versa.  A cookie would be set to save which theme the user is currently on, so when they return they will see the last theme they selected.

How do I change the theme on the fly in wordpress?

Thanks!

Comment: There are a [lot of plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=theme+switch&sort=) with related functionality or are you interested in how to implement this from scratch?

Comment: I'm using a user agent theme switcher plugin that works great, but I want to include a link that will allow the user to have control of which theme is displayed for them.  I wasn't able to find a simple plugin that has this functionality.  I might have missed one though.  Is there a specific one that you know of that have this functionality?  I'm up for writing one from scratch, I'm just unsure what I need to call to switch a theme.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Theme Switch and Preview](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nkthemeswitch/).

If you are up for coding this yourself, you can use the `template` and `stylesheet` filters.

E.g.: to switch to Twenty Ten:

```
function custom_load_twenty_ten_template() {
    return 'twentyten';
}

function custom_load_twenty_ten_stylesheet() {
    return 'twentyten';
}

add_filter( 'template', 'custom_load_twenty_ten_template' );
add_filter( 'stylesheet', 'custom_load_twenty_ten_stylesheet' );
```

Comment: thank you , its working for me , but how i can make this work for a theme listed in a plugin directory /plugins/mobview/theme/ ?! i tried to use " register_theme_directory " then get the mobile theme out of it , but didn't work !!!

Comment: The location of the theme does not matter. If the theme is called Mobview e.g., you will use 'mobview' instead of 'twentyten'.

Comment: thank you @sorich87 your answer really helped me to solve my problem (in fact write my own small plugin).