# Using a Theme inside a Plugin directory

Tags: plugin-development, themes, mobile, wp-redirect

I am building a mobile friendly plugin and put the theme directory inside the plugin directory.

If it's a mobile browser, how can I redirect to the theme in the plugin directory?

```
  /wp-content/plugins/mobview/theme/
```

I've managed to use the following redirection:

```
wp_redirect( plugins_url('/mobview/theme/index.php') );
exit ;
```

But am kind of lost in the directory redirect inside WordPress structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi **@Hamza:**

I think what you are looking to do is for your plugin to hook `'template_include'` to tell it to load a file from your plugin directory. Here's starter code for your plugin:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Mobile View Plugin
*/

if (is_mobile_user()) // YOU NEED TO DEFINE THIS FUNCTION
  class MobileViewPlugin {
    static function on_load() {
      add_filter('template_include',array(__CLASS__,'template_include'));
    }
    function template_include($template_file) {
      return dirname( __FILE__) . '/theme/index.php';
    }
  }
  MobileViewPlugin::on_load();
}
```

Of course this will require that you somehow filter out when it is not a mobile user by defining the `is_mobile_user()` function *(or similar)* and it also means that your `/theme/index.php` will need to handle everything, included all URLs as you've basically bypassed the default URL routing by doing this *(or your could inspect the values of `template_file` and reuse the logic by routing to equivalent files in your plugin directory.)* Good luck.

P.S. This does not provide a mobile solution for the admin. That would be 10x more involved.

Comment: Wow , this actually the 3rd solution works , Thank YOU :D

Comment: @Hamza - Glad I could help.  *(If it is the one that works would you mind if I ask you to select it as the accepted answer? Or at least select one of the answers. Thanks.)*

Comment: welcome , sure will select it .. sorry for late got stuck again at work :(

Comment: @Hamza - Glad it helped!

Answer (score 4):

You misunderstand mechanics of how theme works. It does have `index.php` template, but request is still processed by WordPress main `index.php` in site's root. It makes no sense to redirect visitor to theme's folder because themes are not meant to be visited directly (they expect WP core to be loaded for them and such).

I am not proficient with such plugins, but I imagine they are likely using `template_redirect` hook to load their templates instead of those of active theme on match to mobile browser.

I think they are quite a few plugins on this topic in official repository, you can look through their code to get an ideas for common techniques used.

Comment: i agree with you

Answer (score 2):

if i am not wrong then
try this code

`$includes_path = TEMPLATEPATH . '/your folder name/';`

then write this

`require_once ($includes_path . 'file name');`

Comment: didn't work !!! , i should add this an action to wp_header or where exactly :( ....  i added it in /pulgins/mobview/mobview.php , the wordpress now displaying a blank page !

Comment: the first code should be written on the very first line of your mobview.php and the secod line, when you require that theme file

Comment: hmm ,all i am thinking of now , is when to activate the plugin it will use the theme used in : /wp-content/plugins/mobview/theme/ ... i have red about register_theme_directory but i don't think this will do it .

Comment: did that , didn't work !

Comment: what you want actually?

the files you require? rite?

Comment: well : i am making a mobile theme plugin , so i put the finished mobile theme inside the plugin directory like this /plugins/mobview/theme/ , so i am looking to enable the theme soon as activate the plugin !!!!

Comment: i managed to change to the theme listed in the themes dir. thu i could not get the theme inside the plugin directory , i used this : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3761/switch-theme-on-fly , and now stuck in " register_theme_directory " which seems does not register my new theme directory !

Comment: edit your original question, so people will come to know now your new query

Answer (score 0):

well ,

i think , i mis-explained my question , thu i explained more in the sub-comments :

All i needed is : to activate another theme , in different directory , and to do such thing

first :

register the new theme directory :

`register_theme_directory( WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/mobview/theme' )`;

2nd :

to add a filter to use this theme :

```
function loading_mobv_template() {
    return 'hamzamob';
}

function loading_mobv_style() {
    return 'hamzamob';

 }

dd_filter('stylesheet','loading_mobv_style');
add_filter('template','loading_mobv_template');
```

Now all i need to do is to select if the browser is a mobile or not then activate the action .

Thank you .

---

update :
this is the answer to my first question up . Thank you :)

Comment: @Hamza - Are you answering your own question or just clarifying your question?  If you are clarifying your question please delete this answer and edit your original question to include this.

Comment: @hamza why dont you ask  another question where you have actual doubts, here your question is not proper, try to frame it and ask again, and answer a new question everytime instead edit your original question

Comment: @MikeSchinkel : usually i ask a question and keep searching till i find it , this time i found what am looking for then posted it in here , is this against the rules - thank you :)

Comment: @ntechi : i don't have another question yet and i believe i made myself clear in the first one , sorry for editing the first question to put the code in it .. thank you :)

Comment: @hamza : i am not saying that your question is different, i just want to say that second question you have to frame it, so that we all can understand it, coz your second question is probably your answer to your first question

Comment: @Hamza - Thanks for editing to make it clear that your answer was actually the answer *(of course I don't understand your answer, but then that's probably your lack of English skills which I certainly cannot fault you for; I probably can't write anything in your language. :)*

Comment: @MikeSchinkel : haha , its not about the language its about the lack of sleep , just slept 4 hours after 5 days :D FINALLY ....... can't make english or my own language after complete 5 days without sleeing can i ! thanks anyway ;)

Comment: @ntechi : thanks for getting the first question , and your generous help .

Comment: @Hamza - At the moment I've been up for 36 hours so know somewhat how you feel... :)