# How to assign posts to different themes?

Tags: themes

Let's say I have 2 themes.

1. Theme for girls in pink
2. Theme for boys in blue

I have 2 posts.

1. Post about playing with legos
2. Post about playing with dolls

I would like post 1 to show with theme 1 and post 2 to show with theme 2.

How can I do this in WordPress?

Comment: Do you really want to assign posts to themes, blue to boys and pink to girls? I think you are very confused. Posts belongs to sites, to authors, to taxonomies ..... never to themes. Of course, you can [use different themes based on your desires](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3761/switch-theme-on-fly), like some post's property, but assign posts to themes is a wrong concept just like "pink to girls" or "legos to boys" is a wrong concept

Answer (score 3):

You got some things mixed up here - let me try to point you in the right direction.

### Terminology

In WordPress, a `theme` is a set of files and functions that provide the frontend look for your Website. Most themes also include some specific functionality, but the main goal of a theme is to style your WordPress website according to your needs.

A WordPress website uses one theme, that is one of the most basic settings.

The plugins that you ased for are a way of altering the functionality of your Website.

### WPSE Rules

WPSE is not about plugin recommendations, but a forum to ask specific how-to questions. Please refer to the [Help Center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to learn hw to ask a good question

### A method of solving this problem

Nevertheless, even if your question is not asked in a good way, I would like to provide you with an idea for a solution.

Basically, you want to use different styls for different pages, and WordPress offers a bunch of possibilities to achieve just that.

#### Using different templates

A very simple solution would be to use different templates to achieve a different look for your pages.

If you have a `page-boys.php` and a `page-girls.php` in the root directory of your theme, you can create different layouts for these two.

#### Ading a `body` class

This one is more complicated, as you need to know which class your HTML-`body` should have *before* your content is processed. You could use a hook depending on some `post_meta` to achieve that. Place this function in your `functions.php`, and be sure to create the [post meta data](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) where needed.

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'f711_your_boy_girl_meta_function' );

function f711_your_boy_girl_meta_function( $classes ) {
    if ( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'f711_your_boy_girl_meta', true ) == 'boys' ) {
        $classes[] = 'boys';
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

#### Enqueueing another stylesheet

Basically the same as the body class, you can enqueue a different stylesheet, if some post_meta is set.

### Conclusion

You got a little bit of work to do, but fortunately for you, this is not too hard to do, and it's a great way to learn about how WordPress works.

And please feel free to come back with any detailled questions that may arise on your journey :)

Comment: I tink that OP looks for something like [switching theme on the fly](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3761/switch-theme-on-fly), not to style posts. But who knows, the question is quite poor.

Comment: I understood it as styling posts - _almost_ like having custom post formats but not quite. +1 for a good answer to a poor question.

Comment: Yeah, it was not quite clear, and I think OP was not really sure what to do, therefor I wanted to explain the matter a little better.